# Changing background color if an input is disabled in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Just started using Vue.js so lots to learn. 
I want to change the background color when an input is disabled because a computed function returns true. I can't seem to make it work.

This is in my export default

```
computed: {
  disableField () {
    if (condition) return true
  }
}
```

This is in my template

```
<input
  :class="{ disableInput: disableField }"
  :disabled="disableField"
/>
```

This is in my CSS

```
.disable-input {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

It disables the field when the computed function returns true but it doesn't change the background color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @dziraf pointed out, your class name is `'disable-input'`, so change it to `:class="{'disable-input': disabled}"`, then should work fine.

Or if this input only bind this class, uses `:class="disabled ? 'disable-input' : ''"` is another solution.

Or you may want to use css selector to implement same goal, like:

`input:disabled {
  background-color:red;
}`

Below is one demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      disabled: true
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input:disabled {
  background-color:red;
}

input.disable-input {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="disabled=!disabled">Toggle {{disabled}}</button>
  <input :disabled="disabled" :value="'abc'">
  <input :disabled="disabled" :value="'abc'" :class="{'disable-input': disabled}">
  <input :disabled="disabled" :value="'abc'" :class="disabled ? 'disable-input' : ''">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrected syntax below. Enclose your classname in quotes.:

```
<input
  :class="{ 'disableInput': disableField }"
  :disabled="disableField"
/>
```

Comment: It should be `'disable-input'`.

Comment: @dziraf You're right. `disable-input` works. Thank you! This blog that I was reading about Vue.js said to use camel case :(

Comment: Just read official documentation, it's very good and this topic is covered there too.